# input text field for a particular item in array while mapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, reactjs

Im trying to map over an array and trying to update a particular item based on a button click.

```
<div className="read-data">
    {readData.length >= 1 ? readData.map((res)=>(
     <div>
     <h2>{res.data.message}</h2>
     <button onClick={()=>{
          (setUpdateBox(true))
       }}>
       Update
     </button>
     {updateBox ? (
        <div>
          <form>
            I<input type="text" name="textarea" placeholder="Update message"/>
          </form>
        </div>
     ):null}
      <button onClick={()=>{
        deleteMessage(res)}}> Delete</button>
      </div>
    )):null}
  </div>
```

it opens text area for every item in array. but i want input text box for the only item whos corresponding button is clicked.
plz help how to do it.

Comment: One way to solve this is you'll need to store index of each item and store its state of open/close in your setUpdateBox, so it may look like `setUpdateBox(priorState => {...priorState, i: true })` where `i` is an index. Essentially you are storing your state in an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may find that solution useful for you.

- you need to set a unique index or any identifier to every element.
- on every update or delete operation, you can access the element by its index
- reference the input to get the value by using `ref`

I assume that you pass an array of object as a props

```
const readData = [
  {
    data: {
      message: "new message 1"
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      message: "new message 2"
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      message: "new message 3"
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      message: "new message 4"
    }
  }
];
```

**ReadData Component**

```
function ReadDataComponent({readData}) {
  let inputRef = React.useRef();

  const [updateBox, setUpdateBox] = React.useState(readData);

  const deleteMessage = (i) => {
    const updatedBox = [...updateBox];
    let filteredBox = updatedBox.filter((_, index) => i !== index);
    setUpdateBox(filteredBox);
  };

  const showUpdateBox = (i) => {
    const updatedBox = [...updateBox];
    updatedBox[i].isOpen = updatedBox[i].isOpen ? !updatedBox[i].isOpen : true;
    updatedBox[i].data.message = inputRef.current
      ? inputRef.current.value
      : updatedBox[i].data.message;
    setUpdateBox(updatedBox);
  };

  return (
    <div className="read-data">
      {readData.length >= 1
        ? updateBox.map((res, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <h2>{res.data.message}</h2>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  showUpdateBox(i);
                }}
              >
                Update
              </button>
              {res.isOpen ? (
                <div>
                  <form>
                    <input
                      ref={inputRef}
                      type="text"
                      name="textarea"
                      placeholder="Update message"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              ) : null}
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  deleteMessage(i);
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-knuth-pd85l)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Not sure if you want to use state or props or both etc.

Have a updateBox property on every object in the array, and toggle it between true and false.

You should probably add another function to update the message property as the user types in the input box?

```js
function App(){

  function setUpdateBox(id){
    const copyState = [...readData];
    const thisItem = copyState.find(x => x.id == id);
    thisItem.updateBox = !thisItem.updateBox;
    setData(copyState);
  }
  
  function deleteMessage(id){
    const copyState = [...readData].filter(x => x.id != id);
    setData(copyState);
  }
  
  const initData = [
    {id: 1, updateBox: true, data: {message: "hello"}},
    {id: 2, updateBox: true, data: {message: "world"}},
  ]
  
  const [readData, setData] = React.useState(initData);
  
  return (
  <div className="read-data">
    {readData.length >= 1 ? readData.map((res)=>(
     <div>
     <h2>{res.data.message}</h2>
     <button onClick={()=>setUpdateBox(res.id)}>
       Update
     </button>
     {res.updateBox ? (
        <div>
          <form>
            <input type="text" name="textarea" placeholder="Update message"/>
          </form>
        </div>
     ):null}
      <button onClick={()=>deleteMessage(res.id)}> Delete</button>
      </div>
    )):null}
  </div>
  );
}

  
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```